# How to represent percentages to degrees on a graph?

Tags: trigonometry, percentages

I am trying to visually represent a percentage on a 4 quadrant graph with a line that is supposed to tilt with an angle.

For example:

Clockwise 4 quadrant graph.

```
  270*
180* 0*
  90*
```

I get a percentage back from my calculation: (b-a)/b.
I need to represent this percentage on my graph by tilting the arrow with the correct angle.

For example 20-10/20 = 0.5 or 50%
I would expect this to tilt to the right by 45*.
Like this:

```
\
```

How can I convert my 50% to 45*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use proportions.  If $x$ is the angle corresponding to $50\%$, then 
$$
\frac{x}{90} = \frac{50}{100}
$$
By the way, this manner of measuring angles is referred to as [gradians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradian).